# Cutting of an video by timestamps from a subtitle?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp

I have a subtitle script , I copied the timestamps from that subtitle into text file.From those timestamps I want to modify the original video , cutting of pieces from that original video.I'm not interested on the parts that I'm cutting of , I only care of the remains.I'm seeking the pauses between the subtitle.

Here are the first 20 timestamps.I'm interested in the pauses between the lines , 1 and 2 , 2 and 3 , 3 and 4 and so on.
ffmpeg commands to cut or copy is only outputing the result of those timestamps but is not changing the original video.That is what I want to edit that video by deliting the parts between those timestamps.Is it possible ?

> 1.00:00:45,366 --> 00:00:47,499
>
> 2.00:00:47,500 --> 00:00:51,165
>
> 3.00:00:51,166 --> 00:00:56,132
>
> 4.00:01:47,000 --> 00:01:49,265
>
> 5.00:01:49,266 --> 00:01:51,365
>
> 6.00:02:06,366 --> 00:02:11,665
>
> 7.00:02:11,666 --> 00:02:13,799
>
> 8.00:02:16,766 --> 00:02:20,999
>
> 9.00:02:21,000 --> 00:02:24,732
>
> 10.00:02:24,733 --> 00:02:26,999
>
> 11.00:02:27,000 --> 00:02:30,932
>
> 12.00:02:30,933 --> 00:02:33,465
>
> 13.00:02:33,466 --> 00:02:36,465
>
> 14.00:02:36,466 --> 00:02:37,732
>
> 15.00:02:37,733 --> 00:02:40,299
>
> 16.00:02:40,300 --> 00:02:42,265
>
> 17.00:02:45,300 --> 00:02:48,265
>
> 18.00:02:48,266 --> 00:02:50,532
>
> 19.00:02:50,533 --> 00:02:55,365
>
> 20.00:02:55,366 --> 00:03:02,132

Comment: There's a good tutorial [here](http://markheath.net/post/cut-and-concatenate-with-ffmpeg) on doing just what you want.  Basically you cut out the relevant sections as you've already described, create a text file `inputs.txt` with the list of all your resulting video files, then run the command `ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: Yes , but what I want actualy is the pause between lines.So how to I delete the time between for exemple 00:00:45,366 --> 00:00:47,499 to actually modify the original video ?.It was nice for an editor to have this option available, importing some timestamps and the program to know exactly where to cut.

Comment: You should be able to just parse your text file to get the intervals you want. Grab the last timestamp on a line, and the first timestamp on the next line etc.